# OptaPlanner construction phase - Is there a way to define filters?

Tags: drools-planner, optaplanner

In local search phase you can configure filters for entities, values and moves.
You can even provide a custom move factory if you want.

However, I can't find any documentation on how to do the same in construction phase.
The only configuration is a heuristic type and forager: [Chapter 8. Construction heuristics](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR5/optaplanner-docs/html/constructionHeuristics.html)

I want to implement some of my very hard rules in filters, however, without the ability to filter in construction phase I must also define them as scoring rules to avoid bad construction.

Is there a way to define filters for construction phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is (requires at least `6.0.0.CR1`, but best the latest and greatest), but it's not yet documented.

Follow the rabit hole down from [ConstructionHeuristicSolverPhaseConfig](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/constructionheuristic/ConstructionHeuristicSolverPhaseConfig.java) and QueuedEntityPlacerConfig.
It's something like:

```
   <constructionHeuristic>
     <queuedEntityPlacer>
       <entitySelector id="a"/>
       <changeMoveSelector>
         <mimicEntitySelector refId="a"/>
         <valueSelector>
       </changeMoveSelector>
     </queuedEntityPlacer>
   </constructionHeuristic>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a deep hole. I managed to configure this using the original entity selector. However, I still wonder if the configured change move selector performs like the auto-generated one create the the queued entity placer.